# Quadratic equation - LHS RHS cancelling

Tags: quadratics

I am unable to solve this equation: $$\displaystyle\frac{(12x^2+5x-3)}{(4x+3)} = \frac{(6x^2+13x-5)}{(2x+5)}$$
On solving the LHS and RHS become equal and cancel each other. Much grateful if anyone can help me out.
Shas

Comment: First compute the roots of numerators and you will see what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation is not defined for $x=-\frac{3}{4}$ and $x=-\frac{5}{2}$. The equation is fulfilled for all other real $x$.

Comment: The answer given is x = 1. This is a school grade equation. Is there any process to handle this type of equation?

Comment: Yeah, it is $$\frac{(4x+3)(3x-1)}{4x+3}=\frac{(2x+5)(3x-1)}{2x+5}$$ so your answer is not true.